# How to import csv files with sorted file names?

Tags: python, csv, sorting, merge

I am trying to import multiple csv files and when I run the below code it does work.

```py
allfiles = glob.glob('*.csv')
allfiles
```

However, this results in:

```
['file_0.csv',  
'file_1.csv',  
'file_10.csv',  
'file_100.csv',  
'file_101.csv,  
...
]
```

As you can see, the imported files are not sorted numbers. What I want is to have my numbers in my file names to be in ascending order:

```
['file_0.csv',  
'file_1.csv',  
'file_2.csv',  
'file_3.csv',
...
]
```

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also a way to do that. This algorithm will sort with length of file name string.

```
import glob


all_files = glob.glob('*.csv')

def sort_with_length(file_name):
    return len(file_name)

new_files = sorted(all_files, key = sort_with_length )

print("Old files:")
print(all_files)
print("New files:")
print(new_files)
```

Sample output:

```
Old files:
['file1.csv', 'file101.csv', 'file102.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file201.csv', 'file3.csv']
New files:
['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv', 'file101.csv', 'file102.csv', 'file201.csv']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
allfiles = glob.glob('*.csv')   
allfiles.sort(key= lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `glob`, you need to sort the resultant files yourself by the integer each file contains:

```
allfiles = glob.iglob('*.csv')

allfiles_sorted = sorted(allfiles, key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group()))
```

Also note that, i've used `glob.iglob` instead of `glob.glob` as there is no need to make an intermediate list where an iterator would do the job fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check with [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)

```
from natsort import natsorted
allfiles=natsorted(allfiles)
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir()` will give the list of files in that folder and `sorted` will sort it

```
import os
sortedlist = sorted(os.listdir())
```

EDIT: just specify `key = len` to count the length of an element

```
 sorted(os.listdir(),key = len)
```

Comment: Didn't notice that you want it in `file_1,file_2,file_101` not `file_1,file_101,file_2`, have edited the code have a look